# Error in call to API function "files/download"

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I use DropBox API to implement Dropbox in Xamarin.Forms (NET Standard).
I upload a file success, but when I download I get this error

> Dropbox.Api.BadInputException: Error in call to API function
>   "files/download": Bad HTTP "Content-Type" header:
>   "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".  Expecting one of "text/plain",
>   "text/plain; charset=utf-8", "application/octet-stream",
>   "application/octet-stream; charset=utf-8".

```
using (var client = new DropboxClient(this.AccessToken))
{
    using (var response = await client.Files.DownloadAsync(file.FilePath + "/" + file))
    {
        var pickedFile = await response.GetContentAsByteArrayAsync();
        //FileImagePreview.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() => pickedFile);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you take a look at the following links, as they discusses the same problem you are describing:

- [Content-Type setting for downloading using dropbox api v2](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-Support-Feedback/Content-Type-setting-for-downloading-using-dropbox-api-v2/m-p/311852#M18551)
- [Xamarin Forms and DropBox - get " Bad HTTP Content-Type" error when downloading file](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/143553/xamarin-forms-and-dropbox-get-bad-http-content-type-error-when-downloading-file)
- [Xamarin.DropBox.APi - HTTP 400 (Bad request) on DownloadAsync](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/142057/xamarin-dropbox-api-http-400-bad-request-on-downloadasync)

Hope it helps!